# Facebook Marketing API doesn't return all search entries

Tags: facebook-graph-api

i am building a tool to integrate with Facebook Marketing API. Thats works quite good, but when I want to search now for different targeting categories I just dont get them as results. Here is an example.

[image]

When i search in the Facebook ads manager, there is e.g. a category called "Bike riding" under Demographics > Work > Employers. So now i think that I should get the category when I search for everything under demographics. But the graph explorer for example doesnt have that entrye (and many others as well).

[image]

So this category "bike riding" I cannot find. I am not sure if I am doing something wrong, using not correct category (but as it seems it is under demographics), or wrong type, or whatever. Does anybody has an idea?

THANKS

Comment: Have you checked for pagination links at the end of that list in Graph API Explorer …?

Comment: Good idea, i will check it. It might be that the graph explorer only gives back few results.

Comment: Cheked the results. There is no pagination and when I do search (not through Graph API Explorer, but through cURL) I still have not the result I am looking for.

Comment: Looks like specifying a `limit` doesn’t work either (using for example limit=3 still delivers the same amount as a request with no limit set at all.) Suggest you file a bug report, and ask them if that endpoint is supposed to deliver the same results as in Ads Manager, and if so could they please fix it. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another way to get to the results. When using the targetsearch edge under the account it seems to bring up all results:

[image]

I dont understand completely what the different is between the 2 searches, but at least the second one works. Also there is not a great documentation about. But OK, seems to work.